# run a script after deb package is created with cpack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am trying to create a deb package using cpack. But due to a bug in cpack it is creating file 'md5sums' with wrong permissions and i am getting a warning when installing the deb package using software center. I have a script which will change the permissions of the file from the deb package. But i am confused about how to automatically run the script once the package is made.

Answer (score 1):

You may use post-install script like this:

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${PROJECT_NAME}/contrib/postinst;")
```

Comment: you understood it wrong ... i wanted to change the permission of a file inside the package ... eg the postint script itself

Comment: The CMake's INSTALL command has the PERMISSIONS option - it specifies permissions for installed files. How did you solve your issue?

Comment: no, we cant specify the permissions , because that file is created by cpack iteslf

Answer (score 1):

I used the following method

used a script which has the following content

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
mkdir fix_up_deb
dpkg-deb -x @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@.deb fix_up_deb
dpkg-deb --control @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@.deb fix_up_deb/DEBIAN
rm @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@.deb
chmod 0644 fix_up_deb/DEBIAN/md5sums
find -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755
fakeroot dpkg -b fix_up_deb @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@.deb
rm -rf fix_up_deb
```

Then configured it using

```
CONFIGURE_FILE("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/fixup_deb.sh.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fixup_deb.sh" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
```

Then run it once the package is build using (I havnt tested this step)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET package POST_BUILD COMMAND bash fixup_deb.sh WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

Or run it manually as from the build directory

```
bash fixup_deb.sh
```